# Filtering Pivot Table Using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to write out some VBA code to filter a pivottable of mine to show only records greater than 0.

When I run the code, I receive ther error "Application-defined or object-defined error".

I really have no idea what is causing the issue, so hoping for some assistance from you all!

Here's my code:

```
 Sheet32.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("Retail Division"). _
        PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=Sheet32.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("Sum of Recordable Injuries"), Value1:=0
```

Any ideas why the code is not running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the filter before your line :

```
 Sheet32.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("Retail Division").ClearAllFilters
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!